# Using iText7, how do I fill an otherwise empty column with a rectangle?

Tags: itext

Using iText7 I wish to fill an otherwise empty column with a bordered rectangle headed by some text.  The border methods seem to have disappeared from Rectangle in iText7 and the only examples I can find use them. If Rectangle is the correct approach how do I do this?  If not, what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [Chapter 2 of the tutorial "iText 7: Building Blocks"](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-working-rootelement)

In this tutorial, we create a `Rectangle` object and we draw it to a `PdfCanvas` object:

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(36, 650, 100, 100);
pdfCanvas.rectangle(rectangle);
pdfCanvas.stroke();
```

How to get a `PdfCanvas` object?

Either you create it from a `PdfPage` object you've created yourself:

```
OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(fos);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage();
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
```

Or you get an existing page from the `PdfDocument` object:

```
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdf, pdf.getNumberOfPages());
```

You can tweak the line width, dash pattern, line color,... using different methods in the `PdfCanvas` object.

There are other ways to draw a rectangle, but in one of your previous questions, you mentioned a `ColumnDocumentRenderer`. If your current question is part of the same context, you already have `Rectangle` objects and if you have a `ColumnDocumentRenderer`, you have access to a `PdfCanvas` object. You could easily automate your app to make it draw a rectangle around every column that is rendered.

Of course: since you never accepted my previous answer, my assumption could be wrong.

Comment: If the OP wants to let iText do the layouting, his answer may be more to the point as drawing directly on the canvas bypasses iText layouting. But as you already noted, the OP is quite reluctant to appropriately describe what he wants, so we do not know...

Comment: Most of the high-level objects (`Paragraph`, `Table`, `Cell`,...) have a `setBorder()` method that is implemented for that exact same purpose, but the OP explicitly asked to render a `Rectangle`.

Comment: *but the OP explicitly asked to render a `Rectangle`.* ... and then uses paragraph himself. Oh well... ;)

Comment: We'll have to wait until the sun comes up in the Bay Area to know for sure ;-)

Comment: OP here.  I wanted a rectangle not necessarily a Rectangle.  My Paragraph generated a rectangle.  I gather that the sun has arisen on the Bay Area.  It certainly has on my (Tampa) Bay Area.  Things are nice here on the West Coast.

Comment: Hmmm about half of my "pretty complex" solution was determining the height and width of the (small "r") rectangle to be rendered.  The proposed solution neatly bypasses this by hard coding the height and width.  I have to have this be dynamic as the paper size, number of columns, etc. vary based upon user input.  Taking that out, my solution would be around 4 lines of code but then it would only be a (small "r") rectangle, detumescent but as noted it does let iText do the heavy lifting of layouting..

Answer (score 0):

For better or worse this seemed to achieve my objective:

```
AreaBreak   nextArea    = new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_AREA);
document.add(nextArea);
float h = document.getRenderer().getCurrentArea().getBBox().getHeight();
float w = document.getRenderer().getCurrentArea().getBBox().getWidth();
Paragraph endB = new Paragraph(" ");
endB.setHeight(h);
endB.setWidth(w);
SolidBorder b = new SolidBorder(2);
endB.setBorder(b);
document.add(endB);
```

Comment: That's pretty complex to achieve something so simple. I'll provide another answer.